# Solving second order differential equation 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the initial value problem

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2c}{dx^2} = -\pi^2 x^2c -\pi\frac{s}{\sqrt{c^2+s^2}} \\
\frac{d^2s}{dx^2} = -\pi^2 x^2s +\pi\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+s^2}}
\end{align*}
with inital value $ c(0)=1, \frac{dc}{dx}(0)=0, s(0)=0, \frac{ds}{dx}(0)=0.$

I know that the exact solution is
\begin{align*}
c(x)=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x^2), s(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x^2).
\end{align*}

But, I couldn't derive the solution...

Any help is appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: What ideas do you have?

Comment: Because you have terms like $\sqrt{c^{2}+s^{2}}$, it is tempting to use the "polar" decomposition $c(x)=r(x)\cos{(\theta(x))}$, $c(x)=r(x)\sin{(\theta(x))}$....

Answer (score 1):

Let $$ z(x) = c(x) + i s(x) = r(x)e^{i\phi(x)} $$ then

$$ z'' = c'' + i s'' = -\pi^2 x^2 re^{i\phi} + i\pi e^{i\phi} $$

Furthermore, using the chain rule we can obtain
$$ z' = (r' + ir\phi')e^{i\phi} $$
$$ z'' = \left(r'' + 2ir'\phi' + ir\phi'' -r{\phi'}^2\right)e^{i\phi} $$

Taking the real and imaginary parts we get

$$ r'' - r{\phi'}^2 = -\pi^2 x^2 r \tag{1} $$
$$ 2r'\phi' + r\phi'' = \pi \tag{2} $$

with initial conditions $r(0) = 1, r'(0) = \phi(0) = \phi'(0) = 0$

Since the RHS of $(2)$ is a constant, we guess a constant solution in $r$ or $\theta'$

If $r$ is constant then $r(x) \equiv 1$ and $\phi(x) = \dfrac{\pi}{2}x^2$. This solution also satisfies $(1)$

If $\phi'$ is constant then $\phi(x) \equiv 0$. This does not satisfy $(2)$

So the final solution is

$$ z(x) = e^{i\pi x^2/2} = \cos\left(\frac{\pi x^2}{2}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\pi x^2}{2}\right)  $$

Comment: I appreciated your solution. Thank you! But, I couldn't understand why $r(x)$ and $\phi'(x)$ are constant  from (2). Could you explain about that?

Comment: The LHS must be a constant, so you make a assumption that either $r'$ and $\phi'$ are constant, or $r$ and $\phi''$ are constant. Out of luck, one of them produces a solution that works. This is just a long way of saying "I made an educated guess"

Comment: To be clear, this is definitely not a concrete assumption. It might happen that you don't get a solution at all if you had different initial conditions. Fortunately it doesn't come to that here.